# ¿Como recorrer todos los Rows de un DataTable cuando esta filtrado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Intento recorrer todos los rows que contengan la clase "*highlightchecked*" de un DataTable de jquery usando este código:

```
    $(dtTable12.rows().nodes()).each(function () {
    if ($(this).closest('tbody tr').hasClass('highlightchecked')) {

        var material = {
            materialId: parseInt($(this).find('a[id^=materialId-]').attr('id').substring(11)),
            materialDescripcion: $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text()),
            cantidadProgramada: parseFloat($.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text().replace(/\,/g, ''))),
            cantidadAdicional: 0,
            impuestoId: $('#dropDownImpuestos').val()
        };

        materiales.push(material);
    };
});
```

El código anterior me recorre todos los rows pero solo si están actualmente dibujados en pantalla, osea los 10 que muestra por pagina, no me toma aquellos rows que estén paginados ni los que se ocultan cuando uso el campo **Search** para realizar una búsqueda solo me obtiene los elementos desplegados.

Necesito tomar todos los rows que contengan dicha clase, ya que ciertos valores de ese row son utilizados para otro proceso y requiero de todos los elementos en el que usuario hizo clic.

Gracias adelantadas por cualquier orientación.

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que quieres... O más bien... necesitas tomar todos los valores de tu tabla aunque estén filtrados? Es eso?

Comment: Así es eso es lo que quiero, tomar todos los rows de mi tabla que tengan una clase específica, editare la pregunta explicando esto.

Comment: Que sucede con los otros rows? estan ocultos? Es decir... Si estan ocultos puedes manejarlos si se crean dinámicamente será dificil tratarlos

Comment: Están ocultos, se ocultan al buscar un valor...

Answer (score 3):

En tu código tienes:

> `dtTable12.rows().nodes()`

Creo que solo con `$(dtTable12).DataTable().rows()` ya obtendrías la lista de todos los rows, pero `dtTable12` ¿qué valor tiene?, puedes poner directo con el `id` como en mi ejemplo.

Te anexo mas información al respecto para que la tomes en cuenta, espero que te pueda ayudar, saludos.

En mi caso con el siguiente codigo:

```
$("#example").DataTable().rows()
```

Obtengo todas las filas o renglones de la tabla, y con este codigo:

```
$("#example").DataTable().rows( { filter : 'applied'} ).nodes()
```

Obtengo solo los filtrados.

Prueba con el siguiente ejemplo, filtra con el combo y checa en la consola el número de rows que estoy retornando.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnObtenerValores").click(function(){
    //var columna = $("#txtColumna").val();
    var columna = parseInt($("#cboHeaders").val());
    columna = isNaN(columna) ? 0 : columna;
    ObtenerValoresDataTable(columna);
  });


  // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
  //$('#example tfoot th').each(function() { //Con este ejemplo poniendo en el footer del grid
  var headers = [];
  $('#example thead th').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).text();
    headers.push(title);
    //Si es la columna Office <-- aqui pongo el combo
    if (title == 'Office') {
      //$(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');

      //Recorro todos los rows para obtener los valores
      ObtenerValoresCombo(2,true);
      var combo = '<select style="width:100%">';
        combo += '<option id="0"></option>'
      $.each(valoresCombo, function(i, v) {
        combo += '<option id="' + i + '">' + v + '</option>'
      });
      combo = combo + '</select>';

      $(this).html(combo);
    }
  });
  
  //Pongo la lista de encabezados en el combo de Headers
  //console.log(headers);
  var datosHeader= '';
  $.each(headers, function(i, v) {
    datosHeader += '<option value="' + i + '">' + v + '</option>'
  });
  $("#cboHeaders").append(datosHeader);
      
  // DataTable
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   sort:false
  });

  // Apply the search
  table.columns().every(function() {
    var that = this;

 $('select', this.header()).on('keyup change', function() {
      if (that.search() !== this.value) {
        that
          .search(this.value)
          .draw();
    
  console.log("Filas Totales: " + $("#example").DataTable().rows().count()
       + "\nFilas Filtradas: " + $("#example").DataTable().rows( { filter : 'applied'} ).nodes().length);
      }
    });
 /*
 //Ejemplo con el footer
    $('select', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
      if (that.search() !== this.value) {
        that
          .search(this.value)
          .draw();
      }
    });*/
 
 
 
  });
 //alert("Filas: " + $("#example").dataTable().rows().count());
});



var valoresCombo = [];

//Esta funcion solo FILTRA dentro de los valores mostrados, por eso se ejecuta solo la primera vez, cuando el grid tiene toda la informacion
function ObtenerValoresCombo(columna,showAlert) {
 valoresCombo = [];
 $('#example tbody tr').each(function(indiceFila) {
  $(this).children('td').each(function(indiceColumna) {
   if(indiceColumna == columna){//Indice de la columna Office
    valoresCombo.push($(this).text());
   }
  });
 });
 
 //Remuevo los duplicados
 valoresCombo = valoresCombo.unique();
  if(showAlert){
    alert(valoresCombo);
  }
};


//Para recorrer TODA la informacion sin importar el pagina hay que tomar de base lo siguietne y no el grid como objeto WEB si no como objeto DataTable
function ObtenerValoresDataTable(columna) {
  //console.log(columna);
 var valores = [];
  
  //Obtengo toda la infromacion del GRID TR HTML
  //si esta activo deferRender: true entonces regresara 
  //                            solo la informacion de las paginas del grid vistas
  //var rows = $("#example").dataTable().fnGetNodes();  
  
  //Obtengo los valores del grid sin elemento html
  var rows = $("#example").dataTable().fnGetData()
  //console.log(rows);
    
 $(rows).each(function() {
    valores.push($(this)[columna]);
 });
 
 //Remuevo los duplicados
 valores = valores.unique();
  
  //$("#result").text(valores);
  
  var datosResult= '';
  $("#cboResults").html('');
  $.each(valores, function(i, v) {
    datosResult += '<option value="' + i + '">' + (i+1) +'-' + v + '</option>'
  });
  $("#cboResults").append(datosResult);
};

Array.prototype.unique=function(a){
  return function(){return this.filter(a)}}(function(a,b,c){return c.indexOf(a,b+1)<0
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="prueba2.js"></script>
Columna: 
<!--<input type='number' id='txtColumna' value='2'/>-->
<select id="cboHeaders"></select>
<button id="btnObtenerValores">Obtener Valores</button>
<br>
Resultados:
<select id="cboResults"></select>
<!--<div id="result"></div>-->
<br>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!--<tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>-->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charde Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>2008/10/16</td>
      <td>$470,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2012/12/18</td>
      <td>$313,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>2010/03/17</td>
      <td>$385,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Silva</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2012/11/27</td>
      <td>$198,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paul Byrd</td>
      <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2010/06/09</td>
      <td>$725,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gloria Little</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2009/04/10</td>
      <td>$237,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bradley Greer</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2012/10/13</td>
      <td>$132,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dai Rios</td>
      <td>Personnel Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>2012/09/26</td>
      <td>$217,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
      <td>Development Lead</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2011/09/03</td>
      <td>$345,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yuri Berry</td>
      <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>2009/06/25</td>
      <td>$675,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Caesar Vance</td>
      <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2011/12/12</td>
      <td>$106,450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Doris Wilder</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2010/09/20</td>
      <td>$85,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
      <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/10/09</td>
      <td>$1,200,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>2010/12/22</td>
      <td>$92,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2010/11/14</td>
      <td>$357,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2011/06/07</td>
      <td>$206,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fiona Green</td>
      <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>48</td>
      <td>2010/03/11</td>
      <td>$850,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shou Itou</td>
      <td>Regional Marketing</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>2011/08/14</td>
      <td>$163,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michelle House</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2011/06/02</td>
      <td>$95,400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Suki Burks</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>53</td>
      <td>2009/10/22</td>
      <td>$114,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/05/07</td>
      <td>$145,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
      <td>Team Leader</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2008/10/26</td>
      <td>$235,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Martena Mccray</td>
      <td>Post-Sales support</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/03/09</td>
      <td>$324,050</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Unity Butler</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/12/09</td>
      <td>$85,675</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/12/16</td>
      <td>$164,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
      <td>Secretary</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2010/02/12</td>
      <td>$109,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>2009/02/14</td>
      <td>$452,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2008/12/11</td>
      <td>$136,200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>2008/09/26</td>
      <td>$645,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Olivia Liang</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2011/02/03</td>
      <td>$234,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bruno Nash</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>2011/05/03</td>
      <td>$163,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2009/08/19</td>
      <td>$139,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thor Walton</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2013/08/11</td>
      <td>$98,540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Finn Camacho</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/07/07</td>
      <td>$87,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
      <td>Data Coordinator</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2012/04/09</td>
      <td>$138,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2010/01/04</td>
      <td>$125,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>2012/06/01</td>
      <td>$115,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
      <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2013/02/01</td>
      <td>$75,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cara Stevens</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/12/06</td>
      <td>$145,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hermione Butler</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2011/03/21</td>
      <td>$356,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lael Greer</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2009/02/27</td>
      <td>$103,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2010/07/14</td>
      <td>$86,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shad Decker</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/11/13</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Bruce</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>2011/06/27</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Actualizacion 2018-01-18

Mira en el ejemplo ejecutando desde aqui de stackoverflow:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me esta dando el resultado TOTAL y también el filtrado.

Marcos Giner:  ¿Podrías poner tu código de ejemplo?

Mas o menos entendi lo que quieres hacer y agregue mas informacion al fuente revisalo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. He probado la función "ObtenerValoresCombo" para que me muestre mediante alert los valores de una columna de todas las filas del datatable, pero solo me muestra el valor de las filas actuales, es decir, las que se ven, las filas que estan en otras páginas del datatable no me muestra sus valores.

Comment: Agregue mas información a la respuesta, podrías publicar tu código de ejemplo para ver lo que me dices?

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias de verdad! Me ha servido muchísimo. No se como agradecértelo. Es increíble. Llevaba muchos días con esto hasta que me lo solucionaste. No se como darte las gracias. Es un honor.

Comment: De nada, me da mucho gusto que te haya podido ayudar.  Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tienes problemas con los conceptos de lo que es codigo servidor (en tu caso supongo ASP.NET) y codigo cliente (javascript, html, css).
Una vez que esta en la vista ya no es un DataTable, es una tabla de html.
Segunda, la tabla html solo va a contener los elementos que esta dibujando, osea los que muestra en la pagina actual.
Por lo tanto si quieres revisar las filas de una tabla que estaba en un paginado anterior, vas a tener que guardar que campos eran.
Lo que te recomiendo es cada vez que cambias de pagina guardar cuales filas estan marcadas con la clase *"highlightchecked"*, y cuando necesites todos tus registros vas a tener que ir a donde guardaste tus filas marcadas y ahora si mandarlos al segundo proceso.
Como estamos trabajando con WEB los valores se pierden entre llamadas, asi que tendras que guardarlos en Sesion, tu sesion puede ser de html5 (sesionstorage, localstorage, webstorage), o con tu sesion del servidor (en ASP la variable Sesion).
No se si esto te deje un poco más claras las cosas.
Una vez que te decidas con que tipo de sesion vas a trabajar te podemos ayudar en ver como lo vas a guardar.

Comment: Tu argumento seria valido y totalmente de acuerdo contigo si Jose Luis no hubiera puesto "los rows que contengan la clase "highlightchecked" de un DataTable de jquery"...  Así que esta usando Jquery Datatable: https://datatables.net/    <---- puedes ver la documentación y validar que si pueden guardar datos porque es un objeto y no una simple tabla.

Comment: Buen punto Critina, ese script no lo he trabajado, gracias por el dato.

Comment: Muy recomendable Jquery DataTable, creo que también tiene su versión para Angular 4, es de los mejores grids y mas completos que he usado, aparte que es libre o  "gratis", no tienes que pagar por el, Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tu Recores la tabla con el .each en el selector de jquery. Es por eso que lo hace solo por lo que está en pantalla. Cambialo por [iterator()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/iterator())

```
dtTable12.rows().iterator('row', function (context, index) {
    let node = $(this.row(index).node());
    node.find('.no').val();
    materialDescripcion: $.trim(node.find('td:eq(0)').text());
}
```